# How To merge this three order list to one list with same name item merge to one line？

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have three orders with items what customer bought from shop.
[image]
below is the model of lines on the Order.

```
public class ShopOrderItem {

private String name;
private String itemcode;
private int count;
private double price;
private String taxRate;



public ShopOrderItem() {
    super();
}
public ShopOrderItem(String name, String itemcode, int count, double price,
        String taxRate) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.itemcode = itemcode;
    this.count = count;
    this.price = price;
    this.taxRate = taxRate;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getItemcode() {
    return itemcode;
}
public void setItemcode(String itemcode) {
    this.itemcode = itemcode;
}
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getTaxRate() {
    return taxRate;
}
public void setTaxRate(String taxRate) {
    this.taxRate = taxRate;
}
```

}

and below is how to get the 3 orders.

```
public class testList {

ShopOrderItem a = new ShopOrderItem("apple","001",2,(double)4.00,"0.17");
ShopOrderItem b = new ShopOrderItem("banana","002",1,(double)2.00,"0.17");
ShopOrderItem c = new ShopOrderItem("light","003",1,(double)30.00,"0.17");
ShopOrderItem d = new ShopOrderItem("apple","001",5,(double)4.00,"0.17");
ShopOrderItem e = new ShopOrderItem("light","003",10,(double)30.00,"0.17");
ShopOrderItem f = new ShopOrderItem("apple","001",1,(double)4.00,"0.17");
ShopOrderItem g = new ShopOrderItem("pen","004",3,(double)3.00,"0.17");

List<ShopOrderItem> orderA = new ArrayList<ShopOrderItem>();
orderA.add(a);
orderA.add(b);
orderA.add(c);

List<ShopOrderItem> orderB = new ArrayList<ShopOrderItem>();
orderB.add(d);
orderB.add(e);

List<ShopOrderItem> orderC = new ArrayList<ShopOrderItem>();
orderC.add(f);
orderC.add(g);
```

}

I want to merge this 3  List to one List.
when same name ,add the count.
for example,my new list will have one line ,name is apple, and count is three orders' apple 's sum.
how i merge these three lists?

Comment: did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage: `groupByNameAndSumCount(orderA, orderB, orderC)`

```
static List<ShopOrderItem> groupByNameAndSumCount(List<ShopOrderItem>... orders) {
    List<ShopOrderItem> merged = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<ShopOrderItem> order : orders) {
        merged.addAll(order);
    }

    // group all by name as this is our invariant
    HashMap<String, ShopOrderItem> grouped = new HashMap<>();
    for (ShopOrderItem item : merged) {
        String name = item.getName();
        if (grouped.containsKey(name)) {
            ShopOrderItem current = grouped.get(name);
            // sum count
            current.setCount(current.getCount() + item.getCount());
        } else {
            grouped.put(name, item);
        }
    }

    // reusing to reduce memory footprint
    merged.clear();

    // prepare result
    for (String key : grouped.keySet()) {
        merged.add(grouped.get(key));
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Hope it helps, sir!

Answer (score 0):

you can add the 3 lists to one list, sort it and then put them in a map. then turn the map into a list.

```
    List<ShopOrderItem> merged = new ArrayList<ShopOrderItem>();
    merged.addAll(orderA);
    merged.addAll(orderB);
    merged.addAll(orderC);

    Collections.sort(merged, new Comparator<ShopOrderItem>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(ShopOrderItem o1, ShopOrderItem o2) {
            return (Integer.parseInt(o1.getItemcode()) - Integer.parseInt(o2.getItemcode()));

        }
    });
    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for (ShopOrderItem shopOrderItem : merged) {
        if(map.containsKey(shopOrderItem.getItemcode())){
            int current = map.get(shopOrderItem.getItemcode());
            current+=shopOrderItem.getCount();
            map.remove(shopOrderItem.getItemcode());
            map.put(shopOrderItem.getItemcode(), current);
        }else{
            map.put(shopOrderItem.getItemcode(), shopOrderItem.getCount());
        }
    }
    List<ShopOrderItem> result = new ArrayList<ShopOrderItem>();
    Set<Entry<String,Integer>> set = map.entrySet();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : set) {
        if(entry.getKey().equals(a.getItemcode())){
            ShopOrderItem t = new ShopOrderItem(a.getName(), a.getItemcode(), entry.getValue(), a.getPrice(), a.getTaxRate());
            result.add(t);  
        }else if(entry.getKey().equals(b.getItemcode())){
            ShopOrderItem t = new ShopOrderItem(b.getName(), b.getItemcode(), entry.getValue(), b.getPrice(), b.getTaxRate());
            result.add(t);  
        }
        else if(entry.getKey().equals(c.getItemcode())){
            ShopOrderItem t = new ShopOrderItem(c.getName(), c.getItemcode(), entry.getValue(), c.getPrice(), c.getTaxRate());
            result.add(t);  
        }
        else if(entry.getKey().equals(g.getItemcode())){
            ShopOrderItem t = new ShopOrderItem(g.getName(), g.getItemcode(), entry.getValue(), g.getPrice(), g.getTaxRate());
            result.add(t);  
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8:

```
Collection<ShopOrderItem> result = Stream.of(orderA, orderB, orderC)
                                            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                        ShopOrderItem::getItemcode, 
                                                        Collectors.reducing(new ShopOrderItem(), Use::merge)
                                                    ))
                                            .values();

private static ShopOrderItem merge(ShopOrderItem s1, ShopOrderItem s2)
{
    return new ShopOrderItem(s2.getName(), s2.getItemcode(), s1.getCount() + s2.getCount(), s2.getPrice(), s2.getTaxRate());
}
```

Comment: Note: I'm not totally satisfied with `merge()` because I had to use `s2` in order to avoid some `null` values.